# Extract Color form excel sheet using python

Tags: python, excel

I have requirement where I have to extract the color of the cell(back ground) of a excel file,I have done it in perl but , I need it in python.

Could someone help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use openpyxl library to read and get whats required from excel file. Here is the link to get color [Openpyxl styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/openpyxl/styles/colors.html)

You can use this sample code as

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('#filename', data_only=True)
sh = wb[Sheet1]  
sh['A1'].fill.start_color.index
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`xlrd`](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/):

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from webcolors import rgb_to_name

wb = open_workbook('cel_lis.xls', formatting_info=True)
sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')


def getBGColor(book, sheet, row, col):
    xfx = sheet.cell_xf_index(row, col)
    xf = book.xf_list[xfx]
    bgx = xf.background.pattern_colour_index
    pattern_colour = book.colour_map[bgx]

    #Actually, despite the name, the background colour is not the background colour.
    #background_colour_index = xf.background.background_colour_index
    #background_colour = book.colour_map[background_colour_index]

    return pattern_colour

rgb_Col = getBGColor(wb, sh, 0, 0)
print("The RGB value of the cell is: {} which is equivalent to {}".format(rgb_Col, rgb_to_name(rgb_Col)))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
The RGB value of the cell is: (255, 0, 0) which is equivalent to red
```

> Note:
>
> I used a worksheet of type `.xls` with a name `cel_lis.xls` having its
>   sheet called `Sheet1` with the first cell `A` which has a `Red` background
>   color.
>   [image: out]

Comment: Firstly thanks for the solution, but how to get the information about a entire colum with a few variety of colors

Comment: @SaptarshiBaisya `rgb_Col = getBGColor(wb, sh, 0, 0)` the last value represents the col Value, increasing it would get the next column!